# Mac - Wifi Pen Testing

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I have used Linux in the past for my Wifi pen testing, though that was some time ago and I haven't had a need to do it in some time. I'm now using a Mac running Snow Leopard (Mac Mini) and I'd like to have a go at testing my networks.

Anyone know the best way about doing this on a Mac?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify? You want a Mac program that works like a Wifi Pen?

Comment: @Josh "pen testing" = "penetration testing"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/) looks pretty good:

> iStumbler is the leading wireless discovery tool for Mac OS X,
>   providing plugins for finding AirPort networks, Bluetooth devices,
>   Bonjour services and Location information with your Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would find a pen testing Linux distribution like Backtrack. IMO, if you're pen testing, you should probably use the same guns with the same caliber that the baddies use.

Comment: He asked specifically how to do it on a **Mac**.

Comment: You can run LiveCDs on an Apple Macintosh Computer.